# removing new line character from incoming stream using sed

Tags: shell, sed, csh

I am new to shell scripting and i am trying to remove new line character from each line using SED. this is what i have done so far :

```
printf "{new\nto\nlinux}" | sed ':a;N;s/\n/ /g'
```

removes only Ist new line character.
I somewhere found this command :

```
printf "{new\nto\nlinux}" | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'
```

but it gives :"ba: Event not found."

if i do:

```
printf "{new\nto\nlinux}" | sed ':a;N;s/\n/ /g' | sed ':a;N;s/\n/ /g'
```

then it gives correct output but i am looking for something better as i am not sure how many new character i will get when i run the script.
incoming stream is from echo or printf or some variable in script.

Comment: The 'ba:Event not found' error is from your shell.  Stop using csh, or escape the !.

Comment: @WilliamPursell i have to use csh only no other options for me.on your suggestion i dropped ! "printf "{new\nto\nlinux}" | sed ':a;N;$ba;s/\n/ /g'" this command too is not giving the correct result .. i know there are many disadvantage of using csh but have to use it due to some compulsion :( ..thanks

Comment: You cannot remove the '!', but you need to precede it with a backslash.

Comment: The "found somewhere" might well have been http://stackoverflow.com/a/1252191/512360 - see there for an explanation as to how it works.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

To remove newlines, use tr:

```
tr -d '\n'
```

If you want to replace each newline with a single space:

```
tr '\n' ' '
```

The error `ba: Event not found` is coming from csh, and is due to csh trying to match `!ba` in your history list.  You can escape the `!` and write the command:

```
sed ':a;N;$\!ba;s/\n/ /g'  # Suitable for csh only!!
```

but sed is the wrong tool for this, and you would be better off using a shell that handles quoted strings more reasonably.  That is, stop using csh and start using bash.

Comment: thanks for your reply but you can we use tr with to modify incoming stream from echo or printf??

Comment: Nope, this still does not work.  Even with the `$\!ba`, the result is `ba: Event not found` from a csh script.

Comment: The answer should be `sed ':a;N;$\\!ba;s/\n/ /g'`

Comment: I wanted to replace some but not all newlines in a file. e.g. all lines ending with PULLUP. This worked: `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/PULLUP\n/ /g;'`.

Answer (score 8):

This might work for you:

```
printf "{new\nto\nlinux}" | paste -sd' '            
{new to linux}
```

or:

```
printf "{new\nto\nlinux}" | tr '\n' ' '            
{new to linux}
```

or:

```
printf "{new\nto\nlinux}" |sed -e ':a' -e '$!{' -e 'N' -e 'ba' -e '}' -e 's/\n/ /g'
{new to linux}
```

Comment: +1: Nice usage of paste.  Note that the sed solution here will not work with csh due to the (mis)quoting rules, and the `!` must still be escaped.

Comment: Yay paste. It needs a dash on the end though, to indicate it should read from stdin:  `paste -sd" " -`

Comment: tr -d "\n"  only leaves me with the last line of stdin.. :/ (on Mac)

Answer (score 0):

Use perl instead of sed. perl is similar to sed:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/$ printf "{new\nto\nlinux}" | sed 's/\n/ /g'; echo ''
{new
to
linux}
ubuntu@ubuntu:/$ printf "{new\nto\nlinux}" | perl -pe 's/\n/ /g'; echo ''
{new to linux}
ubuntu@ubuntu:/$ echo -e "new\nto\nlinux\ntest\n1\n2 3" | perl -pe 's/\n/_ _/g'; echo ''
new_ _to_ _linux_ _test_ _1_ _2 3_ _
ubuntu@ubuntu:/$
```