# How to remove header, new line character \ and ""

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, vim

I have file with data as:

```
"S.ACQUIRER||'|'||SUBSTR(S.ACQ_COUNTRY,1,4)||'|'||SUBSTR(S.ACQ_CURRENCY_CODE,1,5)||'|'||S.PAN||'|'||SUBSTR(S.ACCTNUM,1,18)||'|'||SU\    BSTR(I.E_NAME,1,35)||'|'||S.LOCAL_DATE||'|'||S.LOCAL_TIME||'|'||DECODE(S.PCODE,0,'POSTRANSACTIONFROMDEFAULTACCOUNT',1000,'POS"
"9000000007|840|840|5048349120900000008|504834000000006028|Ecustomer name |03-JAN-14|115744|Cash Withdrawal from\
Savings Account |10|Approved |2000061|ATM Test Terminal Bang |123400000123456 |01001101"
"9000000007|840|840|5048349120900000008|504834000000006028|Ecustomer name |03-JAN-14|115744|Cash Withdrawal from\
Savings Account |10|10|4000061|ATM Test Terminal Bang |123450000000456 |01001101"
```

However, the expected output is:

```
9000000007|840|840|5048349120900000008|504834000000006028|Ecustomer name |03-JAN-14|115744|Cash Withdrawal from Savings Account |10|Approved |2000061|ATM Test Terminal Bang |123400000123456 |01001101
9000000007|840|840|5048349120900000008|504834000000006028|Ecustomer name |03-JAN-14|115744|Cash Withdrawal from Savings Account |10|10|4000061|ATM Test Terminal Bang |123450000000456 |01001101
```

The differences are:

1. There should no header line
2. There should no "" at start each line and end as well
3. The escaped new line character (backslash followed by newline) should not present

How to get my requirement?

Comment: might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10618798/removing-new-line-character-from-incoming-stream-using-sed

Comment: The data in the question had no newline after the backslash in the title line, but it is almost certain that the newline should have been present (and, further, the backslash-newline appeared in the middle of SUBSTR, so no space was wanted). Other data lines had trailing blanks after the backslash (and after the closing double quote), but it is almost certain that those should not have been there (but the backslash-newline should be replaced by a space to preserve sensible wording). Is that an accurate assessment? If not, please ensure that the data are accurately represented in the question.

Comment: What have you tried, and where did you fail? By showing your attempts, your gaps in knowledge can be better addressed.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -e '/\\$/N' \
    -e 's/\\\n/ /g' \
    -e 's/^"//' \
    -e 's/"$//' \
    -e '/^[^0-9]/d' \
    "$@"
```

This could be crushed into one unreadable line, but it is easier to explain the five operations when they're neatly separated:

1. If the line ends with a backslash, concatenate the next line into the buffer (pattern space) and restart.
2. Replace any backslash-newline with a space.
3. Delete double quote at the start of a line.
4. Delete double quote at the end of a line.
5. Delete any line that does not start with a digit.

Given a clean version of the input (no trailing blanks), this produces:

```
9000000007|840|840|5048349120900000008|504834000000006028|Ecustomer name |03-JAN-14|115744|Cash Withdrawal from Savings Account |10|Approved |2000061|ATM Test Terminal Bang |123400000123456 |01001101
9000000007|840|840|5048349120900000008|504834000000006028|Ecustomer name |03-JAN-14|115744|Cash Withdrawal from Savings Account |10|10|4000061|ATM Test Terminal Bang |123450000000456 |01001101
```

Comment: Why `/^[^0-9]/d` instead of just `1d`?

Comment: I had `1d` to start with, but when I looked at the data, I found that there was a backslash-space in between `SU` and `BSTR`, which strongly indicates that the heading line was split too.  Given that reading the next line with N changes the line number but that there wasn't a guarantee that there couldn't be multiple continuations, or no continuation, it is risky to use `2d`.  So, I opted to recognize that the first field in the data appears to be numeric.  (See also my comments to the main question.)  For this file, `1,2d` would be an option (it would be step 0, before the current step 1).

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
awk '/\\$/&&NR>2{sub(/\"/,"");printf $0;next}NR>2{sub(/\"/,"");print}' file
```

**Output:**

```
$ cat file
"S.ACQUIRER||'|'||SUBSTR(S.ACQ_COUNTRY,1,4)||'|'||SUBSTR(S.ACQ_CURRENCY_CODE,1,5)||'|'||S.PAN||'|'||SUBSTR(S.ACCTNUM,1,18)||'|'||SU\
BSTR(I.E_NAME,1,35)||'|'||S.LOCAL_DATE||'|'||S.LOCAL_TIME||'|'||DECODE(S.PCODE,0,'POSTRANSACTIONFROMDEFAULTACCOUNT',1000,'POS"
"9000000007|840|840|5048349120900000008|504834000000006028|Ecustomer name |03-JAN-14|115744|Cash Withdrawal from\
Savings Account |10|Approved |2000061|ATM Test Terminal Bang |123400000123456 |01001101"
"9000000007|840|840|5048349120900000008|504834000000006028|Ecustomer name |03-JAN-14|115744|Cash Withdrawal from\
Savings Account |10|10|4000061|ATM Test Terminal Bang |123450000000456 |01001101"
```

```
$ awk '/\\$/&&NR>2{sub(/\"/,"");printf $0;next}NR>2{sub(/\"/,"");print}' file
9000000007|840|840|5048349120900000008|504834000000006028|Ecustomer name |03-JAN-14|115744|Cash Withdrawal from\Savings Account |10|Approved |2000061|ATM Test Terminal Bang |123400000123456 |01001101
9000000007|840|840|5048349120900000008|504834000000006028|Ecustomer name |03-JAN-14|115744|Cash Withdrawal from\Savings Account |10|10|4000061|ATM Test Terminal Bang |123450000000456 |01001101
```

Comment: Awk golf: `NR<2{next}{sub(/"/,"")}/\\$/{printf $0;next}{print}`

Comment: @PeterRincker Indeed! `:)`

Answer (score 0):

open this in vim,execute this

```
:%s/^"//g

:%s/"$//g

:%s/\\//g
```

but I don't know how to recognize header yet

Comment: Delete the header via `:1d`. See `:h :d` and `:h [range]` for more information

Comment: Look at the sample text:  if a line ends with "\", then remove it and join with the next line.  So `%s/\\\n/ /` instead of simply removing the backslashes.  Probably do this before removing the `"` characters.